# Unable to authenticate GCP IAP

Tags: windows-10, network-connection

I am trying to use IAP Desktop to log into my GCP instances. However, when I am trying to log into the IAP desktop application using my Google account, it is not allowing me to authenticate at all. Ideally when you click on "Sign in with Google" it should pop open a browser window to authenticate. But in my case, it gives error as "Authorization Failed: network location cannot be reached".

[image: Please find below the screenshot for error]

Comment: Error itself clearly states that it couldn't reach the network. As explained in [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/iap-desktop), you need to check whether the VM is having a Public IP address or exposed RDP publicly.

Comment: I think it's not the issue. i understood that even the login page doesn't appear. @Abhishek, are you behind a firewall? Can you test with a direct internet connection and see if it's better?

Comment: @Digil The VM has a public address. I am able to take the remote desktop via mstsc. As I stated in my question, I am not even able to reach into the GCP environment because the login page itself is not coming.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I tried doing this. I turned off the antivirus, turned off the firewall, tried adding IAP in the firewall exception rules, still the same error message. It looks like IAP is not able to access the internet on my system, I don't know why.

Comment: After you've completed the sign-in steps in the browser window, IAP Desktop opens connections to `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/`, `https://accounts.google.com/` and `https://openidconnect.googleapis.com` to complete the authorization. One of these requests seems to fail. Do you use a Proxy, VPN, special DNS settings, or anything alike?

Please feel free to file an issue on https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/iap-desktop (I am the author of the tool)

Comment: @JohannesPassing Just to reiterate my concern, the browser window itself is not opening to complete the sign-in steps. I am not using and proxy\VPN and DNS settings are set to obtain automatically. As you suggested, I have also raised the issue on Github.